# ImportError: No module named mysql

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\AppServ\www\pythonWeb\MySqlConn.py", line 1, in <module>
    import mysql.connector
ImportError: No module named 'mysql'
```

I got the above error message while trying to import mysql.connector
I'm using a Window with python 3.4.2 and Appserv 2.5.10 for Window
I've saved the python file under the folder of AppServ.

Please help.

Comment: so do you have mysql module?

Comment: `mysql` isn't part of the standard library, so you have to install it yourself if you want to use it. Download it from https://pypi.python.org/pypi/MySQL-python.

Comment: Tried to download via the link you shared, however, when I tried to install it, it stated that it only support python 2.7. Does it mean I'll need python 2.7 to be installed first?

Answer (score 3):

Error clearly shows you do 'not have the module "Mysql" which you are importing in order to process further.

```
ImportError: No module named 'mysql'
```

[image]
What you can do depending on OS you are using :

### Windows

```
pip install mysqlclient
```

If you need 1.2.x versions (legacy Python only), use `pip install MySQL-python`

Note: Some dependencies might have to be in place when running the above command.

### Ubuntu 14, Ubuntu 16, Debian 8.6 (jessie)

```
sudo apt-get install python-pip python-dev libmysqlclient-dev
```

### Fedora 24:

```
sudo dnf install python python-devel mysql-devel redhat-rpm-config gcc
```

### Mac OS

```
brew install mysql-connector-c
```

if that fails, try

```
brew install mysql
```

once you install the module successfully re-run your script and it should work

Comment: I added `pip install mysqlclient` before `pip install mysqlclient` , however I got a "invalid syntax"

Comment: For me pip install mysqlclient works just fine i am on windows 10 & using python 3.6.x -->Added image